# Create Multiple Edges at once and align them very precisely with extrude? (Watch Video as Ex.)

Tags: modeling, interface, edges

Visit https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TrZU6-jr8VU
time at 20:26 - 20:43.

I know that you can create an edge with <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> but how does he manage to create multiple edges at once and align them with other edges very precisely? If you know, can you please tell me what the controls are or what tools he used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like he's using *Extrude* (<kbd>E</kbd>) in combination with [*transform snapping*](http://blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/snap.html#transform-snapping) (magnet icon in the header).
You can also toggle transform snapping on the fly by holding <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> during the modal transform (no need to click the magnet icon constantly):

[image]

Where it looks like he extrudes several individual edges, I think he extruded faces but they where hidden due to [backface-culling](http://blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/shading.html#shading-panel) and inverted normals. In the example gif I selected these and flipped their normals with <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to make them visible.

Note that in the video he merged double vertices manually after extruding (<kbd>W</kbd> *> Remove doubles*), but it's possible to have blender do this on the fly by enabling [*automerge*](http://blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/basics/deleting.html#automerge-editing) in the header.